# making sure my thumbnail description is always aligned to the middle of my thumbnail?

Tags: html, css

I have a set of thumbnails that have a little piece of descriptive to the right, what I want to do is make sure no matter if there is 1 line of text, 2 lines or 3 lines that the text is always consistently positioned inline with the middle of the thumbnail? Ive tried giving .desc a height the same as the thumbnail, ive tried vertical-align:middle, ive tried display:table cell but i cant come up with anything that works (for me anyway). if anyone could offer a solution that would be great.

HTML

```
<ul id="container">
    <li>
        <a href="#">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/120x80/000/fff" />
        <p class="desc">This is the text on 2 lines</p>            
        </a>
    </li>  
<li>
        <a href="#">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/120x80/000/fff" />
        <p class="desc">This is the text</p>            
        </a>
    </li>  
<li>
        <a href="#">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/120x80/000/fff" />
        <p class="desc">This is the text going onto 3 lines</p>            
        </a>
    </li>      
</ul>​
```

CSS

```
#container li{float:left;width:230px;margin-right:10px;}
#container li a{position:relative;display:block;}
#container li a img{float:left;}
#container li a .desc{position:absolute;right:0;width:100px}​
```

Link to fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Luvq3/1/

Comment: Have you tried to use tables? Could help you in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML

```
 <ul id="container">
            <a href="#">
                <div class="column"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/120x80/000/fff" /></div>
                <div class="column rightcol"><p class="desc">This is the text</p></div>           
            </a>
        </li> 
    <li>
            <a href="#">
                <div class="column"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/120x80/000/fff" /></div>
                <div class="column rightcol"><p class="desc">This is the text</p></div>           
            </a>
        </li> 
     <li>
            <a href="#">
                <div class="column"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/120x80/000/fff" /></div>
                <div class="column rightcol"><p class="desc">This is the text</p></div>           
            </a>
        </li> 
    <li>
            <a href="#">
                <div class="column"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/120x80/000/fff" /></div>
                <div class="column rightcol"><p class="desc">This is the text</p></div>           
            </a>
        </li>     
     <li>
            <a href="#">
                <div class="column"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/120x80/000/fff" /></div>
                <div class="column rightcol"><p class="desc">This is the text on two lines lol</p></div>           
            </a>
        </li>      
    </ul>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

CSS:

```
#container li{float:left;width:230px;margin-right:10px;}

.column {display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle}
.rightcol {width:100px;}​
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the height of the thumbnail, why not absolute positioning?

```
#container li a .desc { position:absolute;right:0; top: 20px; width:100px }
```

Just control your .desc with a `substr` so it doesn't spill over below the thumb?

Comment: setting top at 20px isnt going to keep all my descriptions consistently positioned although? i basically want the middle of each block of text to be inline with the middle of the image

Comment: If the height of the image is fixed then I don't see why not. You might want to have some control of the description if you want it that exact. Use a substr controlling the length of the description, and absolutely position it. As both of these elements will be a known height, I can't see why you would not use absolute.